# Ordering query with feathers-sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js, feathersjs, feathers-sequelize, feathers-hook

I am trying to write a hook which adds ordering to a query on a table with associations. My query is on 'points' which has a join-table 'point_photos' and then is associated m:n to 'photos'. The standard feathersjs $sort can not be used for associated sorting, so I tried to set sequelize '[order](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#ordering-eager-loaded-associations)' in a hook and this works splendidly. Now I would like to set the 'order' from a find query:

```
        return app.service('points').find(
          {
            query: {
              point_id: [1, 2, 5],
              include: ['PointPhotos'],
              order: [
                [
                  'point_id',
                  'DESC'
                ],
                [
                  'PointPhotos',
                  'photo_id',
                  'DESC'
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        );
      })
```

But now I get:

```
error:  SequelizeDatabaseError: column points.order does not exist
```

Which is odd to me as hook.params.sequelize looks the same to me for the hook and the query...

Also when I simplify the find query 'order' I get the same error; is adding 'order' to the query object not allowed?

EDIT:
I managed to hack around it by adding the order to the 'include' option:

```
return app.service('points').find(
              {
                query: {
                  point_id: [1, 2, 5],
                  include: { include: ['PointPhotos'], order: [
                    [
                      'point_id',
                      'DESC'
                    ],
                    [
                      'PointPhotos',
                      'photo_id',
                      'DESC'
                    ]
                  ]
                 }
                }
              }
            );
          })
```

And adapting my association hook accordingly. This is a bit silly though as in sequelize 'order' is at the same level as 'include', so it confuses things. My question still boils down to: Why does the 'order' key in the query object not work? It looks like it is considered a table-field somehow.